# How can I download symbols for an Business Central App outside of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: http, visual-studio-code, basic-authentication, dynamics-business-central

I am using Business Central SaaS. In Visual Studio Code, I can run "Download Symbols" to download the Application and System app shipped by Microsoft. I now want to do this outside of Visual Studio Code within a github workflow. In VS Code, I can see that the URL looks like this

```
GET https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/Dev/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=18.0.0.0
```

I use a HTTP-Client to test the URL, but I always get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized as response. I tried the folowing credentials:

*bcuser* | *bcpassword*

*bcuser* | *Web Service Access Key*

The user I am testing this is a SUPER user on the sandbox. It is the same user I use when I download symbols within VS Code. I tested it with and without domain name.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JenKoc's answer put me on the right track. I had to add the Tenant-ID to the URL. Downloading Symbols does work with Basic Auth. This is how it works:

1. Get Credentials from Business Central's *User* page. If the Web Service Access Key is empty, just click on the three dots and craete a new one.
   [image]
2. Create a HTTP GET Request with Basic Auth

   User: <User Name>

   Password: <Web Service Access Key>

   URL:

   ```
    https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<tenant-id>/<sandboxname>/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=18.0.0.0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Tenant-Id in the URL and also have to use oauth.

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/<your tenant id>/sandbox/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=18.0.0.0
```

[See Postman Screenshot of GET Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QButn.png)

[See Postman Screenshot of Auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCOeg.png)

Comment: +1 for your answer. I was tempted to accept your answer but it is not 100% correct because I figured out that Basic Auth does indeed work, I just had to add the Tenant-Id.